# Can all solvable algorithm problems being measured by the seven common order of magnitude functions?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm learning about Big-O notations, and they mentioned these 7 common order of magnitude functions including constant, Logarithmic, Linear, Log Linear,Quadratic, Cubic and Exponential.

I'm wondering if all solvable algorithms can be measured in these functions or the combinations of these functions(In the Big-O sense). If not, what are some other uncommon order of magnitude functions?

Comment: Well, the obvious is that Bogosort has no upper bound...

Comment: And Bogosort has an expected time of `(n-1) n!`, which is also none of these.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity mentions factorial and double exponential, among others that are not on your list.

Comment: One example that can't be fit into any of those categories is the Ackermann function:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

It grows faster than exponential, or than exponential of exponential and so on, more than any chain of exponentials. That's just the values, even printing the digits out takes log(Ack) time, which is still more than any chain of exponentials

Comment: Thank you guys so much! All these have been massively helpful!